# Не компилится дерево на СИ

Tags: c, компиляция, дерево, malloc

Qt Creator ругается на 77 строку(пометил комментарием):
main.cpp:77: ошибка: assigning to 'TREENODEPTR' (aka 'treeNode *') from incompatible type 'void *'
При этом в онлайн-компиляторах (например, Onlinegdb) все работает. В чем проблема?

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

#include<time.h>

struct treeNode{

struct treeNode *leftPtr;

int data;

struct treeNode *rightPtr;

};

typedef struct treeNode TREENODE;

typedef TREENODE *TREENODEPTR;

void insertNode(TREENODEPTR *, int);

void inOrder(TREENODEPTR);

void preOrder(TREENODEPTR);

void postOrder(TREENODEPTR);

int main()

{

int i, item, n;

TREENODEPTR rootPtr=NULL;

srand(time(NULL));

printf("Enter n ");

scanf("%d", &n);

printf("The numbers degin placed in the tree are:\n");

for(i=1; i<=n; i++){

item=rand()%15;

printf("%3d", item);

insertNode(&rootPtr, item);

}

printf("\n\nThe preOrder traversal is:\n");

preOrder(rootPtr);

printf("\n\nThe inOrder traversal is:\n");

inOrder(rootPtr);

printf("\n\nThe postOrder traversal is:\n");

postOrder(rootPtr);

return 0;

}

void insertNode(TREENODEPTR *treePtr, int value)

{

if(*treePtr==NULL){

*treePtr = malloc(sizeof(treeNode)); //--------ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ ОШИБКА--------


if (*treePtr!=NULL){

(*treePtr)->data=value;

(*treePtr)->leftPtr=NULL;

(*treePtr)->rightPtr=NULL;

}

else

printf("%d not insert. No memory available.\n", value);

}

else

if (value<(*treePtr)->data)

insertNode(&((*treePtr)->leftPtr), value);

else

if(value>(*treePtr)->data)

insertNode(&((*treePtr)->rightPtr), value);

else

printf("dup ");

}

void inOrder(TREENODEPTR treePtr)

{

if(treePtr!=NULL){

inOrder(treePtr->leftPtr);

printf("%3d", treePtr->data);

inOrder(treePtr->rightPtr);

}

}

void preOrder(TREENODEPTR treePtr)

{

if(treePtr!=NULL){

printf("%3d", treePtr->data);

preOrder(treePtr->leftPtr);

preOrder(treePtr->rightPtr);

}

}

void postOrder(TREENODEPTR treePtr)

{

if(treePtr!=NULL){

postOrder(treePtr->leftPtr);

postOrder(treePtr->rightPtr);

printf("%3d", treePtr->data);

}

}
```

Comment: Зачем же вы нас обманываете? Рассказываете про С, а на самом деле компилируете этот код как С++.

Comment: да еще маллок в объект возвращаете, а не в указатель (о чем и кричит компилятор).

Comment: @Alexander Chernin: Там возвращение в указатель. Там за typedef-именем еще один указатель спрятан. Ужас нечитаемый, конечно.

Comment: Я не в коем случае не обманываю. Я искренне не понимаю, код ведь целиком написан на СИ, разве есть разница, как он компилится?

Comment: @Анон: Что значит "есть разница"??? Если вы напишете программу на Паскале и затем скормите ее компилятору Фортрана, то ничего осмысленного из этого не получится. Так зачем же вы программу на С пихаете в компилятор С++?

Comment: Ранее все работало. Странно. Запихнул в компилятор для Си, все равно та же ошибка

Comment: @AnT Закомпилилось) Спасибо большое. Я зарегистрировался на форме только пару дней назад, я могу вас как-то отблагодарить?

Comment: @Анон: Что значит "запихнул"? У вашего файла расширение - `.cpp`. Большинство компиляторов будут расценивать его как C++, пока вы силой не переключите их в режим С. Вы переключали?

Comment: меня всегда интересовало, как можно так криво скопировать код, что в итоге он будет записан через строку? (вопрос не риторический)...